# Codeception. Как использовать несколько урлов в одном тесте?

Tags: test-automation, codeception

Сразу скажу что с codeception я не особо дружу, да и в целом в автоматизации днарь.
Появилась необходимость использовать две вьюхи (админка и сам сайт) в одном acceptance тесте. Как это реализовать не имею ни малейшего представления.
Хотелось бы сделать что-то типа такого:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
// Перехожу на сайт и выполняю какие-то действия
$I->amOnPage('http://mysite.com');
// some code

// Далее перехожу в интерфейс админки и совершаю там некоторые действия
$I->amOnPage('https://edit-mysite.com');
//some code

// Затем снова перехожу на сайт и смотрю применились ли изменения
$I->amOnPage('http://mysite.com');
// some code
```

Но в таком случае к указанным урлам подставляется url, прописанный в конфиге acceptance.suite.yml и тест пытается перейти на сайт http://mysite.com/http://mysite.com или в случае с админкой на http://mysite.com/https://edit-mysite.com.

Может есть какие-нибудь инструменты позволяющие прописывать абсолютные урлы в amOnPage()?

Может у кого-то есть идеи как это реализовать? Или кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей? В любом случае буду рад вашим советам и помощи с вашей стороны!

Answer (score 1):

Решено! Проблема была в том что я использовал метод amOnPage(), вместо метода amOnUrl().

Спасибо Naktibalda за помощь!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360680/codeception-how-can-i-use-more-then-one-url-in-my-acceptance-test#new-answer